# Problemas con checkbox

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente checkbox en HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label  class="col-sm-3 control-label" id="albaran_abono"for="abono">Albarán de abono:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
     <div class="checkbox-inline">
      <input type="checkbox" name="abono" id="input-abono"  tabindex="2"/> 
     </div>
   </div>
```

Si el checkbox está 'checked' descargo en la tabla albarandeventas campo abono -1 y si no lo está 1.

El problema está al recuperar los datos de la tabla. Necesito  que al editar el albarán, en la línea correspondiente al checkbox, éste aparezca con la señal de 'checked' y visualmente el usuario lo compruebe. He intentado lo siguiente:

```
 <div class="checkbox-inline">
   input type="checkbox" name="abono" id="input-abono"  tabindex="2"value="{{$albaran->abono ===1?'': 
   'checked' }}"/> 
  </div>
```

Espero haberme explicado, gracias anticipadas

Comment: No relacionado con tu pregunta, pero una cosa que puede ser de ayuda: el atributo `for` del `label` debe tener el valor del `id` del campo de destino en lugar del `name`. Tal y como está ahora, el `label` y el `input` no están relacionados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con PHP puedes realizar lo siguiente:

- Dentro del input, puedes realizar la llamada a una validación, entonces asignas las condicionales necesarias, en caso de cumplirse, agregas el texo `checked` para marcar la opción de antemano.

---

```
<?php
echo "Si esta variable es 1, se marca - variable: ";
$f = 1;
echo $f;
?>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="abono" id="input-abono" tabindex="2" 
    <?php if ($f === 1) {
        ?> checked <?php
    } ?>
    /> Checkbox
</div>
// -----------------------------------------
<?php
echo "Si esta variable es 0, no se marca - variable: ";
$f = 0;
echo $f;
?>
<div class="checkbox-inline">
    <input type="checkbox" name="abono" id="input-abono" tabindex="2" 
    <?php if ($f === 1) {
        ?> checked <?php
    } ?>
    /> Checkbox
</div>
```

Obteniendo como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Excorpion, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema de la pregunta, deberías añadir una breve descripción del cambio que hiciste para solucionar el problema. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código sin una descripción clara suelen ser más difíciles de entender por otros usuarios. Lee [answer] para más información.

Comment: @ excorpion  Estupendo functiona: pregunta ¿Puedes decirme donde me equivoco? en el código  value= "{{($albaran->abono === 1) ? ' ': "checked" }}" en síntesis parece el mismo

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Agregada una breve descripción.

Comment: @EDiaz Yo el unico error que veo, es que lo estás tratando de poner dentro del value. (comente esto antes, pero no estaba seguro)